# CSS path to element using multiple pseudo-classes/elements not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I was wondering if its possible to target an element by stacking pseudo classes.

I tried this:

```css
#advertise .row:first-of-type .one-third:nth-of-type(2) .contentwrap {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

but it only works if us the ID for the rows [#one or #two] in place of the .row:first-of-type/.row:last-of-type

Is this because i cant target elements using multiple pseudo's or am im just doing something silly and not realising?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="advertise">
    <h1 class="maintitle"></h1>
    <h2 class="maintitle-sub"></h2>

    <div class="contentwrap">
        <p></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="one">
        <div class="one-third first shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">                
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="two">
        <div class="one-third first shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">                
                <p></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="one-third shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third shadow">
            <h1 class="header"></h1>
            <div class="contentwrap">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: James Donnelly's answer already covers your problem, but to be perfectly clear - "stacking" pseudo-selectors in the way you're attempting works just fine.

Comment: Is your objective to target a specific `div.contentwrap` or all of them?

Comment: the specific one mentioned in the example above - the .contentwrap in the 2nd one-third in the first row.

Comment: Just a comment but that looks like a very fragile selector. I would higghly recommend finding a simpler way to write it or make sure it is commented in your cSS so you remember WTH you were trying to target.

Comment: @RReveley: what do you mean fragile selector? im using #advertise #one .one-third:nth-of-type(2) .contentwrap.

Comment: There is a lot of nesting and reliance on the markup never changing. 

It also doesn't really say what is does meaning that if you or another dev come back to this in a few months you will have to parse against the HTML to figure out what you are styling.

For example: If I wrote a selector like #advertise ul I would understand what is being styled without looking at the markup and wouldn't need to comment it. 

#advertise .row:first-of-type .one-third:nth-of-type(2) .contentwrap probably does the job but without looking at your HTML would you understand what it is for?

Comment: @Moose My comment is based on inheriting CSS for a large ecommerce platform and refactoring it and rebuilding it over the course of a few years.  Orphaned CSS (that's what I call CSS that I look at and think 'What is that? Does that still do anything?') is a pig as you loose confidence in how your edits and clean-ups may affect the result.

Comment: @RReveley: oh i see what your saying. I read that as advertise page, 2nd row of content, second column, content wrapper. Since there are literally 3 columns per row visually it makes it pretty simple to find without looking at the html, in my personal opinion. All other classes are generalised as well [row, one-third, contentwrap] and are the same all over the site regardless of where they are.

Comment: @RReveley: i just didnt want to have to add a ID for that one box because to me that would of been more confusing going back later on. I mean, what on earth would i call that one box in the second row in the second column on the main advertising page? its either gonna be really long, or too vague to be of use later. The CSS path i used, to me, are like reading directions on a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:first-of-type` selector selects the first instance of a specific type of element (e.g. `<div>`). Here, your first `.row` element is the *second* `<div>` element, and thus your `:first-of-type` selector does not select it.

Instead, you can use:

```css
#advertise .row:nth-of-type(2) .one-third:nth-of-type(2) .contentwrap {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

But as it already has an `id` attribute (which should be unique to that element), you may as well stick with:

```css
#advertise #one .one-third:nth-of-type(2) .contentwrap {
  font-size:16px;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, i see. I was under the impression that it would select the first instance of .row, not the first instance of a/the div!

Comment: The first suggestion in this answer works, but makes a lot of assumptions about the actual markup, which is contrary to how class-based styling should work. Upvoted for reflecting that there is a better way, yet including it for completeness' sake.